# Copy ODBC Driver to another computer

Tags: windows, drivers, odbc

I am trying to copy multiple installed `ODBC` drivers from one computer to another.

I can see the driver name, version, company, file name, and date but no way to export it. Both computers run the same operating system (`Windows 7`, `64bit`) and have very similar system specs.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are the driver name, version, company, file name?  Others can help you far better with this information than without it...

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to copy the files, but to actually use the drivers is a bit more complicated than that.  You would need to not only copy them into the correct directory, but you'd have to register them as well.

The best way to do this is to find and run the installers.  Most of these drivers will be free from the company website and if they're not free no one should help you copy them in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. The driver's are for connecting to a very old legacy system and unfortunately, installers are unavailable to me/us. If I find the file and move them in the correct folder and register them, would this work?

Comment: Yes.  That would work.  If you are using a very old legacy system, the company may have been purchased and the drivers may have been merged with the new ones that are coming out.  It may be worth checking into especially since these drivers will cease to work at some point in the future.